# ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement entity framework genareted sql script

Tags: oracle, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dbeaver

I am trying to run scripts generated from the test environment in the prod environment. The scripts created by **Entity Framework Core 2.2**. But when i execute generated sql scripts in **Dbeaver 6.2.2** i get **ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement**.And bind pop up always show up.

```
[Parameters=[:myParam='filter' (Size = 450)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='0']
SELECT "w"."Foo"
FROM "FooSh"."Foodb" "w"
WHERE ("w"."Foo" = :myParam)
```

[image: Dbeaver bind pop up]

If scripts are wrong, how does it work in entity framework? And how do I execute it successfully?

Answer (score 0):

In DBeaver execute only

```
SELECT "w"."Foo"
FROM "FooSh"."Foodb" "w"
WHERE ("w"."Foo" = :myParam)
```

Your query correct, DBeawer ask binding params with :

Comment: How to execute it without answer binding params?Like copy logs and paste execute ?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand. How you execute query in DBeaver? if you execute SELECT "w"."Foo"
FROM "FooSh"."Foodb" "w"
WHERE ("w"."Foo" = :myParam). This query execute right or not?

Comment: No i execute like question [Parameters=[:myParam='filter' (Size = 450)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='0']
SELECT "w"."Foo"
FROM "FooSh"."Foodb" "w"
WHERE ("w"."Foo" = :myParam) i have a lot of generated query by entity framework starts with [Parameters=[:myParam='filter' (Size = 450)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='0']